# how to set image into div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit a image into div but something going wrong, actualy i just want when i set a image into div it should not affect the div property.

i am trying like this:

```
#image_try {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
       color-stop(0%, white), color-stop(15%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 55%, #D5E4F3 130%);
    float: right;
    border: 2px;
    color: #FF0000;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 164px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 78px 31px 7px 233px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 79px;
    margin-top: -174px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-image:url(images/weather.jpg) no-repeat;
  }
```

**updates:**

Actualy when i did not set image in background then div  looks like good but when i am setting image its height and width being affected

any idea... answer will be fully appreciate...thank you

Comment: post your html, a fiddle will be good.

Comment: please describe more.. which properties of div get affecting by image??

Comment: i think your image size must be greater than your div, isn't it ? if you make a fiddle it can help us more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see few dupe in your css like for background, you using color twice also you are setting it to gradient for Chrome and Firefox. You are repeating margin too. As far as i can under stand your problem was with `padding`. I removed that only. Kindly check the css and provide screenshot if possible.

```
#image_try {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
border: 2px;
color: #FF0000;

width: 164px;

height: 79px;
background-image:url(images/weather.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**Try above edited answer**

Comment: Ideally an answer should not just be code, but an explanation of why the code works.

Comment: not working....Actualy when i did not set image in background then div  looks like good but when i am setting image its height and width being affected

Comment: Thank you for amending your answer @Amit.

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia see my updated answer. Attach screenshot of current as well as of expected output(if possible)